# How to extract several groups by sole function call?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Performance issue. So far, I have extracted each group by recall `substitute` builtin vim script function:

```
let match_pattern = '\(expr1\)\(expr2\)\(expr3\)'
let g1 = substitute(string, 'match_pattern, "\\1", "")
let g2 = substitute(string, 'match_pattern, "\\2", "")
...
```

How to avoid extra `substitute` calls, since it is evaluated the same groups each time?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: VIM Plugin. Just a wrapper over 'find' and 'grep', which optimized to use all cpu cores to increase searching speed